# Spark data denormalization

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DF or RDD where the data goes like [(1element,[2elements],[3elements])]
or each line could look some like >>

```
a_data1, List[b_data1,d_data2], List[c_data1, c_data2, c_data3]
```

As my output Id like to get 6 lines in that case like

```
a_data1, b_data1, c_data1
a_data1, b_data1, c_data2
a_data1, b_data1, c_data3
a_data1, b_data2, c_data1
a_data1, b_data2, c_data2
a_data1, b_data2, c_data3
```

What's the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Dataset`:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*

Dataset<Row> df;


df
  .withColumn("firstColumnName", explode(col("firstColumnName")))
  .withColumn("secondColumnName", explode(col("secondColumnName")));
```